# Dummit Foote Ch 6.1 Q34

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime dividing the order of the finite solvable group $G$. Assume $G$ has no nontrivial normal subgroups of order prime to $p$. Let $P$ be the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. Prove that $C_G(P) \leq P$, i.e. $C_G(P)=Z(P)$. Hint: Show that $C_G(P)=Z(P)\times H$ for some hall $\pi$-subgroup $H$ of $C_G(P)$ where $\pi$ is the set of all prime divisors of $|C_G(P)|$ except for $p$.

$C_G(P)$ is a normal subgroup of G, $Z(P)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ since $Z(P)$ char $P\unlhd G$, but I can't prove that $C_G(P)=Z(P) H$. I also know that since $Z(P)$ is a normal p-subgroup, for every $Q\in Syl_p(C_G(P))$,$Z(P)\leq Q$ from a previous exercise. But I don't know why there can't exist some $x \in Q-Z(P)$. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $C_G(P)$ is not contained in $P$. So $P$ is strictly contained in $PC_G(P) \unlhd G$.

Let $K/P$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G/P$ with $K/P \le PC_G(P)/P$. Since $P$ is the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$, $K/P$ cannot be a $p$-group, so it is an elementary abelian $q$-group for some prime $q \ne p$. Let $q^k$ be its order.

Then $q^k$ must divide $|C_G(P)|$, so $K$ has a Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q \le C_G(P)$, and then $[Q,P]=1$ so we have $K = P \times Q$. But then $Q$ is a normal $q$-subgroup of $G$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing.

Comment: I didn't find the hint very helpful!

Comment: Sorry :X The only other solution source I could find which followed the hint made a really large jump in logic. (https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780471433347-abstract-algebra-third-edition/200/exercises/34)

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't quite understand all the steps to your solution, namely why $PC_G(P)$ is normal in $G$, why $Q\leq C_G(P)$, and why $Q$ being normal in $G$ is a contradiction to the assumption. Additionally, would you know how to resolve the logical leap in the link bluemystic sent, namely that "$x\in Q-Z(P)$ contradicts maximality of $P$"? I would really like to find a solution to the exercise alongside the lines of the hint but am dearly struggling.

Comment: After giving it more thought I managed to fill in all the gaps: many misconceptions on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q\in Syl_{p}\left(G\right)$. The centralizer is a normal subgroup. In particular, $C_{Q}\left(P\right)=Q\cap C_{G}\left(P\right)\unlhd Q$ so $C_{Q}\left(P\right)\in Syl_{p}\left(C_{G}\left(P\right)\right)$ and $C_{Q}\left(P\right)\leq P$. Then $C_{Q}\left(P\right)=Z\left(P\right)$ and it follows in the generalized sense of $N$ (Exercise~6.1.33) where the Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ is replaced by its Hall counterpart $H$ that $C_{G}\left(P\right)=Z\left(P\right)H$ and $\left[Z\left(P\right),H\right]=1$ ([Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt)) so $H$ is normal in $C_{G}\left(P\right)$ and $C_{G}\left(P\right)=Z\left(P\right)\times H$. Observe that the Hall subgroups have the conjugation properties of Sylow subgroups so a normal Hall subgroup is characteristic. Then $H$ is normal in $G$ so $H=1$. It must be that $C_{G}\left(P\right)=Z\left(P\right)$ so $C_{G}\left(P\right)\leq P$. Thus the result.